# Using rad notification as confirm meessage

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Can I Use RadNotification as confirm message with submit and cancel button, Is that scenario is available with this telerik control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RadNotification is only for notifications, a beautiful one. You must use RadWindow instead. You can see the documentation [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/browserdialogboxes/defaultcs.aspx).

Hope it helps.